# Ecto: Include join schema field in many_to_many query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a many_to_many association with an explicit join_schema that references the same model on both ends (kind of like the classic Follower (is a user) <-> Followee (is a user) thing).

To stick with the example if I query for the followers of a user I want to include the time when the followed the user. This data obviously is located on the join schema (let's call is Subscription).

If would just want the followers I would do it like this:

```
followers = User
|> Repo.get!(user_id)
|> assoc(:followers)
|> Repo.all()
```

To have this working I would have defined this on the user:

```
many_to_many(
  :followers,
  MyApp.User,
  join_through: MyApp.Subscription,
  join_keys: [followee_id: :id, follower_id: :id]
)
```

So let's say there is a `created_at` field on the `Subscription` model. How would I query to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the `Subscription` schema, you can define a `has_many`:

```
schema "users" do
  ...
  has_many :follower_subscriptions, MyApp.Subscription, foreign_key: :followee_id
  has_many :followee_subscriptions, MyApp.Subscription, foreign_key: :follower_id
end
```

And then get the subscriptions using:

```
follower_subscriptions = User
|> Repo.get!(user_id)
|> Repo.preload(follower_subscriptions: :follower)
|> Repo.all()
```

`follower_subscriptions` will then be a list of `Subscription`, each containing `created_at`, `followee`, `followee_id`, and `follower_id`.

<sup>Code untested; let me know if there's a typo.</sup>

Comment: Well I had this already but thought it would be possible to get a list of -in this case - followers. I wanted it this way because the subscription list broke phoenix's `render_many`.

Anyway, I tried it one more time and found out that it infers the key from the schema name which obviously won't match because it's a "FollowerView". But there is a way to explicitly define it.

So problem solved, thx! :)